# asp.net add control dynamically to position

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to add 3 radio buttons into each table cell that I create dynamically but they all position themselves outside of the cells and line up from the top most of the page:

[image]

I want the RadioButton created to position inside of the table cell. How do I do this? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Here's my code:

```
                int count = 0;
                int countRB = 0;
                if (dataReader.HasRows)
                {                    
                    testLabel1.Text = "dataReader.HasRows: " + dataReader.HasRows;                  
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        count += 1;  

            htmlString.Append("<table border = '1'>");
                        htmlString.Append("<tr>");
                        htmlString.Append("<td>");                       

                        for (int i = countRB; i < countRB + 3; i++)
                        {
                            RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();

                            // Set the label's Text and ID properties.
                            rb.Text = "RadioButton" + (i+1).ToString();
                            rb.ID = "RadioButton" + (i + 1).ToString();
                            test_populatePlaceHolder.Controls.Add(rb);
                            // Add a spacer in the form of an HTML <br /> element.
                            test_populatePlaceHolder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
                        }
                        countRB = count * 3;
                        htmlString.Append(dataReader["dateTime"] + "<br />" + dataReader["statistics"]");
            htmlString.Append("</td>");
                        htmlString.Append("</tr>");
                        htmlString.Append("</table>");
                        htmlString.Append("<br />");
                    }                
                    test_populatePlaceHolder.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = htmlString.ToString() });
                    dataReader.Close();
                    dataReader.Dispose();
                }                
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply add radio button like:

```
<span><input type="radio" id="rd1" />SOMTEXT </span>
```

So in your code:

```
for (int i = countRB; i < countRB + 3; i++)
                    {
string tmptxt="<span><input type=\"radio\" id=\"RadioButton" + (i+1).ToString()\" />"RadioButton" + (i+1).ToString()</span>";

htmlString.Append(tmptxt)
}
```

Comment: Well put and very simply. Thanks.